# Changing the image in a html img tag using buttons and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a javascript loop that changes the image of a specified tag every x seconds, but when I modify it to only run when I click a button, it does nothing.

The javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var step = 1
    var image1 = new Image()
    image1.src = "img1.jpg"
    var image2 = new Image()
    image2.src = "img2.jpg"
    var image3 = new Image()
    image3.src = "img3.jpg"
    function slideit() {
        if (!document.images) return

        document.images.slide.src=eval("images"+step+".src")

        if (step < 3)
            step++
        else
            step=1
    }

    //-->
</script>
```

The button code:
`<input type="button" name="btnnext" value="Next Picture" onclick="slideit" />`

I have tried changing to `onclick="slideit()"` but that states

"Uncaught ReferenceError: images1 is not defined"

I am not sure where to go from here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: because your variable names are image1 image2, etc, no `s`

Comment: Your slideIt function needs work, there is no reason to use eval. If the src is always "img" + step + ".jpg" you can just use this pattern rather than creating a new Dom element for each one only to grab the src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It should be `onclick='slideit()'`
2. The reason you're getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: images1 is not defined` is because it's trying to `eval('images1.src')` and (I don't think) there's such a variable in your code as `window.images1`, `window.images2` or `window.images3`.

What you probably want instead is to define an `array` of `src`s, and then get `srcsArray[step]` and use that as your new `src` for your `document.images.slide`.

As @patrick-evans said though, you could probably fix it by changing your `eval` to `eval('image' + step + '.src')`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, changing the 'images' to image fixed it! Weird because that's what broke the code when I was looping it.
For the other sections I will use arrays, as the seem much more stable.
Thanks again!